# Filter Views in Drupal - select nodes from taxonomy with children

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm using drupal 7 with views 3. I added some filters to the page and one filter is taxonomy. This taxonomy has a tree structure. Filter is exposed, so the user can change it. Everything works fine but there is one major bug. 
Example structure:

- Parent 1

  - Child 1
  - Child 2

    - Subchild 1
- Parent 2
- ...

When I select for example Child 1 I can see all the nodes from the child 1 - that's ok. But for example when I choose Child 2 I can't see nodes from Subchild 1. Same situation if I choose Parent 1 - i see only nodes exactly from Parent 1 - Child 1,2 and Subchild 1 are not displayed.

Is it possible to show all children with parent with views? Or maybe I should do something like extract all the children manualy from code, than alter the query and make WHERE IN condition?

All help will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 2):

Use the filter 'Has taxonomy terms (with depth)'